# Mobile Push Contact Key Setup

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

I have a question regarding SFMC Mobile Push. Please find below scenario

Install the App on IOS

It created a new Contact Key (123456) in Mobile Push (since we are not passing the contact key, the default GUID is set by the SDK)

Once I login in the app and the following gets updates for ContactKey 123456 (these attributes auto-populates based on the existing API calls to SFDC)

a. FirstName

b. LastName

c. EmailAddress

d: Unique person contact key

Now I want to copy the mobile push attributes from ContactKey 123456 and add or update against the contact key ( Unique person contact key), and then delete the ContactKey 123456. I am doing this to generate the single subscriber view, since I use Unique person contact key for email sends, SMS. And my intent is to use the Unique person contact key for Mobile Push sends.  Please note that we are using the [Cordova plugin](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MC-Cordova-Plugin) for Mobile Push.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another strategy to consider would be to set the initialization flag that prevents the SDK from sending a registration before your `ContactKey` is set.  Also, a point of clarification, the SDK does *not* set a `ContactKey` on your behalf.  If you have not set one in the SDK then the server side creates one when the device is registered.  This is an important distinction because the SDK has no insight into this value.

By utilizing the aforementioned flag you would then simply set additional attributes for the contact when the user logged into your application.

Aside from that you'd have to create an API integration app and make the appropriate API calls to fetch contact details and delete the contact.

Comment: We want to target the users who have installed the application but not yet logged in the mobile push app. If I set the contact key only after a user logging in the app, then I will lose the users who have installed the app but not logged in yet.

Comment: Correct.  That's going to require you to get the data from the Marketing Cloud Servers via API and set it through the SDK.